# VB SQL Multithreading, Database Class, table mixing

Tags: sql, vb.net, multithreading, class

I have a VB project that uses multi threads.

I have a class for all database communications.

Each thread has an instance of the database class.

The main program requests data from an sql command, this works fine most of the time.

When a thread is doing updates and the main program requests data from a table it appears to recieve the wrong table! its looks like it recieves the table one of the threads has asked for/is using.

Am I missing something or missunderstanding how threads and classes in VB work?

Any advice will be gratefully recieved

Comment: Need to see some code.

Comment: Most probably you are executing the wrong query or misunderstand how databases work.  Please show the code.

Comment: OK, in my main code i'm using Dim clsDBReadLocal As New clsDatabase to create an instance of my database class, i create a connection string etc. I use this to get my table  dsAlarmScreen = clsDBReadLocal.GetSQLQueryInDataset(strSQL).  If nothing else is going on this gets the correct information back.                                                               if my thread is using the database I get back the wrong table.